# Replacing text from a file in Java

Tags: java, string, file, replace

I've been trying to create a simple program, in java, that replaces some words into a file. To change the text into the file I created, I create a String and set it to the file text:

```
Path path = Paths.get("somePath/someFile.someExtension");
Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
String s = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
```

EDIT: To save to the file with `s`, I used `Files.write(path, s.getBytes(charset));`.

Then I change the String with commands like `s.replaceAll("A", "B")`. But now, I'm stuck. I want to make a more complicated then just replacing "A" with "B". I'll try to explain has best I can:

I need to find at the file if `wall someNumber someNumer someNumber` is in there, and if there are three arguments (`someNumber someNumber someNumber`), then get the value of "`someNumber`" at the center. For example:

If the commands are:

```
wall 200 500 100
wall 200 500 100
```

Then I want to get the argument from the center (in the first case 500 and in the second 500), and store it into a variable, then delete it from the String. After that, on the top of these commands (in the example `wall 200 500 100 wall 200 500 100`), I want to write:

```
usemtl texture
ceil (someNumber that we stored, in the case, 500)
```

Note that if the arguments `wall wall` don't have any kind of separation (for example `#other wall`), then the someNumber at the center will be equal (500 and 500 are equal). So, the command below will just appear per group (if `wall wall wall...` isn't separed with `#other wall`, for example).

Other example, this would be the file before / after:

Before:

```
wall 100 300 50
wall 100 300 100
wall 100 300 400
```

After:

```
usemtl texture
ceil 300

wall 100 50
wall 100 100
wall 100 400
```

So, how can I make this replace?

Please answer! I have no idea how!

### EDIT: question to @Roan, owner of most of this code:

Now, after the answers @Roan code transformed into:

```
package com.fileConverter.main;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class FileReplace extends JFileChooser {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -254322941935132675L;

    private static FileReplace chooser = new FileReplace();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        chooser.showDialog(chooser, "Open");
    }

    public void cancelSelection() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void approveSelection() {
        super.approveSelection();
        System.out.println("starting...");

        // The path were your file is
        String path = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        File file = new File(path);

        // try to create an inputstream from the file
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // If we are here the file is not found
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // make it a buffered reader
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(fis));

        // to store the current line
        String line;

        // array to store the different words
        String[] words;

        // create a second temporally file that will replace the original file
        File file2 = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getParentFile()
                + "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$.tmp");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        // and create the streams
        FileOutputStream file2Os = null;
        try {
            file2Os = new FileOutputStream(file2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file2Os);
        try {
            System.out.println("replacing code...");
            writer.println("mtllib textures.mtl");
            // loop through all lines and
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                line = line
                        .replace("//", "#")
                        .replace("(", "wall")
                        .replace(")", "\n")
                        .replace("{", "")
                        .replace("}", "")
                        .replace("# brush from cube",
                                "room cube" + countWords(line, "cube"))
                        .replace(" NULL 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0", "")
                        .replace("\"classname\"", "")
                        .replace("\"worldspawn\"", "");

                // get all the diffent terms
                words = line.split(" ");

                // see if there are 4 terms in there: wall x x x
                // and if the first term equals wall28
                // and if the middle number is the number you want to delete
                // if not just copy the line over

                if (words.length == 4 && words[0].contains("wall")) {
                    double doubleVal = Double.parseDouble(words[2]);
                    int val = (int) doubleVal;
                    // now modify the line by removing the middel number
                    String newLine = words[0] + " " + words[1] + " " + words[3];
                    String valInsert = null;

                    if (val >= 0)
                        valInsert = "\n" + "usemtl texture" + "\n" + "ceil "
                                + val;
                    else if (val < 0)
                        valInsert = "\n" + "usemtl texture" + "\n" + "floor "
                                + val;

                    // write this to the new file
                    writer.println(valInsert);
                    writer.println(newLine);
                } else {
                    // copy the old line
                    writer.println(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // close our resources
        writer.close();
        try {
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // now we rename the temp file and replace the old file
        // with the new file with the new content
        file.delete();
        file2.renameTo(file);

        System.out.println("done!");
    }

    public int countWords(String string, String word) {
        int lastIndex = 0;
        int count = 0;

        while (lastIndex != -1) {

            lastIndex = string.indexOf(word, lastIndex);

            if (lastIndex != -1) {
                count++;
                lastIndex += word.length();
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

The problem is that this part doesn't make any replaces:

```
if (words.length == 4 && words[0].contains("wall")) {
    double doubleVal = Double.parseDouble(words[2]);
    int val = (int) doubleVal;
    // now modify the line by removing the middel number
    String newLine = words[0] + " " + words[1] + " " + words[3];
    String valInsert = null;

    if (val >= 0)
        valInsert = "\n" + "usemtl texture" + "\n" + "ceil "
                + val;
    else if (val < 0)
        valInsert = "\n" + "usemtl texture" + "\n" + "floor "
                + val;

    // write this to the new file
    writer.println(valInsert);
    writer.println(newLine);
}
```

How can I fix it? Other thing, this part is suppose to create a number that grows after checking how many times cube is wrote, but it doesn't works too :(

```
.replace("# brush from cube", "room cube" + countWords(line, "cube"))
```

The `countWords` method:

```
public int countWords(String string, String word) {
    int lastIndex = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while (lastIndex != -1) {

        lastIndex = string.indexOf(word, lastIndex);

        if (lastIndex != -1) {
            count++;
            lastIndex += word.length();
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

**Many Thanks**

Comment: Please clarify your question. You want to write: PS....

Comment: Yes, I know that it can look complicated. I fixed PS, now try to read it again. If you don't understand something, then comment, that I'll answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I'm very unsure if I understood this correctly.
This is my interpretation of wat your question is:
You have a file with lines that say: wall [number] [number] [number]
Now you want to check if there there are 3 numbers and then delete the middle number if it's the number you're searching for.

So I would do this like this:
Befor you run the programm you'll need a folder on your C: drive with the name "text" and inside that folder you'll need a file called text.txt with you format in it so: for example:
wall 123 300 320
If you change the value of number you can specify wich number the middle number has to be in oder for it to be deleted.

```
public class FileReplace {

public static void main(String[] args){
    //The path were your file is
    String path = "C:\\text\\text.txt";
    File file = new File(path);

    //The number you want to delete
    int number = 300;

    //try to create an inputstream from the file
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        //If we are here the file is not found
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //make it a buffered reader
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    //to store the current line
    String line;

    //array to store the different words
    String[] words;

    //create a second temporally file that will replace the original file
    File file2 = new File("C:\\text\\$$$$$$$$$$.tmp");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    //and create the streams
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fos);
    try {
        //loop through all lines and 
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            //get all the diffent terms
            words = line.split(" ");

            //see if there are 4 terms in there: wall x x x
            //and if the first term equals wall
            //and if the middle number is the number you want to delete
            //if not just copy the line over
            if(words.length == 4 && words[0].equals("wall") && words[2].equals(String.valueOf(number))){
                //now modify the line by removing the middel number
                String newLine = words[0] + " " + words[1] + " " + words[3];

                //write this to the new file
                writer.println(newLine);
            }else{
                //copy the old line
                writer.println(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //close our resources
    writer.close();
    try {
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //now we rename the temp file and replace the old file
    //with the new file with the new content
    file.delete();
    file2.renameTo(file);
}
```

}

If you have ay questions about this code feel free to ask them.
Oh and also you might need to run this with administrator right as it uses files.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll try it too. +1

Well, you kinda understood. The numbers of the command "wall" could be in any amount. So the file could be:

`wall 100 400 100
wall 300 400 400
wall 500 400 200
wall 200 400 600`

(Note that the middle number is equal). Then I delete the middle number (that is equal and store it into a variable). After that I create other code at the top of the commands (other example, based on the first one):

`usemtl texture
ceil (middle number, that repeats HERE)

wall 100 400 100
wall 300 400 400
wall 500 400 200
wall 200 400 600`

Comment: Ok glad I could help. Do I need to modify my code or can you handle I youself now?

Comment: I don't think that I could change the code by myself.

Comment: Ok if I have some time I'll modify it if you want. But it might also be a good idea to understand the code and be able to chage it yourself. So if you have any questions about it. Jusk ask me.

Comment: Yeah, now I can understand your code! Thanks, I'll modify it by myself.

Comment: Bad news. I've got a problem. How can I check if `words[2]` is negative? And, how can I remove the **double** value of it (if it has one)?

Comment: To check if it's negative do: if(Integer.parseInt(words[2]) < 0){//code} that should work if it doesn't I'll think of something else. And for doubles you can split the string at the '.' character to get an array of with two string one before the dot the other behind the dot, the code is just: String[] array = words[2].split("."); you just use the first number now and convert it.

Comment: What would be an easy way to replace "//" with "#" in the given code?

Comment: Did you mean this? : if(Integer.parseInt(words[2]) < 0){#code}

Comment: And if it's in a programm you can do text.replace("//", "#");

Comment: Wait do you mean in my first code? Because I recently wrote a programm that swaps on term with an other.

Comment: I mean in this BufferedReader program (that you just posted).

Comment: ah I get it. I have a programm that can do it (I'll upload it if you want me to) or I can post an other answer were all the // are # choose wich way. I'll do it tomorrow.

Comment: My idea is to create a program that converts a file to other kind of file. To do it, I have to replace "//" with "#", add in the top "mtllib textures.mtl", make the replace that I asked in the question, replace "(" with "wall", replace ")" with "\n", remove "{" and remove "}", remove arguments after "wall number number number", remove ""classname"", remove ""worldspawn"", replace "# brush from cube" with "room cube" + (number that gets bigger after one argument).

Comment: Yeah for those things you can really use the replace method in String. just say a line:'line.replace("//", "#");' and it will will replace all ocurences of the character sequence // with #. Smiliarly you can do: 'line.replace("(", "wall");' and ( will be replaced by wall. And to add mtllib textures.mtl on the first line. You you write it to the first line before the while loop start like: 'writer.println("mtllib textures.mtl");' Hope this helps and I that I understood you question correctly.

Comment: The mtllib thing works, but the "//" with "#" didn't.

Comment: Oh that's weird I'll try to find a way that does work. And when I find one I'll post it here.

Comment: Oh, I see. Instead of using `line.replace()` we need to use `line = line.replace().replace()...`.

Comment: Yeah because it returns the new string. It doesn't alter the old string because that's imposible because strings are immutable. But I guess it's also my fault I forgot to mention it returns the new string, sorry for that. But I am happy to see you figuered it out.

Comment: No problem that's what this forum is all about. And I really enjoyed helping you ;). Good luck with the rest of your programm.

Comment: Now, I'm getting other problem... It is now in the question.

PS: I hope I'm not giving too much work. Answer just if you have time. :D

Comment: Sure I'll take a look at it :D. This might take a while though.

Comment: I re-wrote your count words method. Shall I create a new answer or edit this answer?

Comment: Thanks again. You are a really good person :D. PS: Post the code in another answer, so I can give +1.

Comment: I posted my answer. I am still working on the other question.

Comment: And what about the `usemtl textures ceil someNumber`? I want, for example, change this: `// brush from cube
( 400 100 200 ) ( 300 -100 300 )`


to this: `cube1

usemtl texture
ceil 100
wall 400 200

usemtl texture
floor -100

wall 300 300`. PS: Post it in another answer for other +1 :D

Comment: I've got a solution :D. I'll post it in a few minutes :D.

Comment: Answer posted as a new answer :D.

Comment: Thank you I really like it to help you :D

Answer (score 1):

To analyse a string and see if it matches ("wall" number number number), you can use a REGEX expression: see the doc [here](http://ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-1/).

To use the regex expression, just apply .matches() on your String variable and it'll return true or false depending on if the format is verified.

If the format is verified, then just use the SubString function, specify the start and end index so you get the middle number.
To take it out, you could do the opposite. SubString the start (everything until middle number), then SubString the end (everything after the middle number), and then create a new string using those 2.

Comment: Thanks with your answer and with the others I solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution without using (explicitly) regex is to split the `String` using token (in your case it's a white space.

```
line = "wall 100 300 50";
String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
```

You can then get the words[2] convert to an `int` etc. Then you can write back to a new file (or the same if you have read all file contents).

Regex are more powerful but to me a bit more intimidating so you can pick whatever matches your needs.

Comment: "\\s+" is regex and it's translates as 1 or more whitespaces (that match the regex). This could be 1,2,3 spaces, 1 or more tab tab (\t) etc. See regex for more details

Comment: Thanks with your answer and with the others I solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this to count the number of occurances of a word in a string:
Try 1:

```
public static int countWords(String string, String word) {
    //get all individual words
    String[] terms = string.split(" ");
    //this variable counts how many times word occurs
    int count = 0;
    //a count variable for the loop
    int counter = 0;
    //loop through all the words and if we see a word that equals word we add one to the count variable
    while(counter < terms.length){
        //check if the term equals the word
        if(terms[counter].equals(word)){
            //the term matched add one to the count variable
            count++;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    //return the number of occurrences
    return count;
}
```

Try 2:

```
public static String countWords(String string, String word) {
    //get all individual words
    String[] terms = string.split(" ");
    //this variable counts how many times word occurs
    int count = 0;
    //a count variable for the loop
    int counter = 0;

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("1");
    //loop trough all the words and if we see a word that equals word we add one to the count variable
    while(counter < terms.length){
        //check if the term equals the word
        if(terms[counter].equals(word)){
            //the term matched add one to the count variable
            count++;
            sb.append(" " + word + (count + 1));
        }
        counter++;
    }
    //return the number of occurrences
    return sb.toString();
}<br><br>
```

Try 3: you need to have a static variable in your code called lastVar:

```
static int lastVar = 0;
public static String countWords(String string, String word) {
    //get all individual words
    String[] terms = string.split(" ");
    //this variable counts how many times word occurs
    int count = 0;
    //a count variable for the loop
    int counter = 0;

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("1");
    //loop trough all the words and if we see a word that equals word we add one to the count variable
    while(counter < terms.length){
        //check if the term equals the word
        if(terms[counter].equals(word)){
            //the term matched add one to the count variable
            count++;
            sb.append(" " + word + (count + 1 + lastVar));
        }
        counter++;
    }
    lastVar += count + 1;
    //return the number of occurrences
    return sb.toString();
}
```

That should work.

Hope this helps :D.

Comment: I don't get it entirely. Do you have a line with cube with a number after it?

Comment: Well, now the problem is how to use this method to count how many cubes are wrote. PS: I'm doing this to don't repeat the term after room. So I'm trying to add 1 after every time room is wrote. For instance: `room cube1 room cube2...` (feel free to ask if you don't understand what I'm talking about... I'm probably a bad person for explanations...)

Comment: Exactly. I need to change the argument after cube (cube1, cube2...). Think it like a variable, two can't have the same name.

Comment: Ah so you want to change this: cube cube cube cube to: cube1 cube2 cube3 cube4   ?

Comment: Also if that is it is cube0 also valid?

Comment: You don't need to check if cube is also valid. And yes, `change this: cube cube cube cube to: cube1 cube2 cube3 cube4`.

Comment: Updated it. This work a little different, but if the line is for example: room cube cube cube cube  it will be room cube1 cube2 cube3 cube4 afterwards. P.S. it now returns a string that comes after what you had.

Comment: And the other problem I ran the programm on my computer and the output was: usemtl texture
ceil 323
wall 234 234 so...

Comment: Also you'll have to add a method that see the number of cubes and returns that as a cube string and use that in the first term of the replace method.

Comment: You kinda understood. I need to do it not just in a line, but in the whole code.

Comment: Well as you're looping through every line that mehod is applied to every line so just add an extra variable. I'll add the code in a minute.

Comment: No problem :). Does this do what you want it to do?

Comment: Yes, one of the things.

Answer (score 1):

To reformat your cube lines you could use:

Try 1:

```
// loop through all lines and
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.contains("// brush from cube")){
                line = line.replace("// brush from cube ", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "");
                String[] arguments = line.split("\\s+");
                line = "cube" + Cube + " usemtl texture ceil " + arguments[2] + " wall " + arguments[1] + " " + arguments[3] + " usemtl texture floor " + arguments[5] + " wall " + arguments[4] + " " + arguments[6];
                Cube++;
            }
            line = line
                    .replace("//", "#")
                    .replace("(", "wall")
                    .replace(")", "\n")
                    .replace("{", "")
                    .replace("}", "")
                    .replace(" NULL 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0", "")
                    .replace("\"classname\"", "")
                    .replace("\"worldspawn\"", "");
```

try 2:

```
// loop through all lines and
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.contains("// brush from cube")){
                line = line + bufferedReader.readLine() + " " + bufferedReader.readLine();
                line = line.replace("// brush from cube ", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "");
                String[] arguments = line.split("\\s+");
                line = "cube" + Cube + " usemtl texture ceil " + arguments[2] + " wall " + arguments[1] + " " + arguments[3] + " usemtl texture floor " + arguments[5] + " wall " + arguments[4] + " " + arguments[6];
                Cube++;
            }
            line = line
                    .replace("//", "#")
                    .replace("(", "wall")
                    .replace(")", "\n")
                    .replace("{", "")
                    .replace("}", "")
                    .replace(" NULL 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0", "")
                    .replace("\"classname\"", "")
                    .replace("\"worldspawn\"", "");
```

P.S. I've only posted the important part. You should be able to see where in the code this goes. Also you need to have a static int called cube somewhere in you code like:

```
static int Cube = 1;
```

That should be it if it doesn't work let me know! :D

Comment: In this file: `// brush from cube
( 400 100 200 ) ( 300 -100 300 )

// brush from cube
( 400 100 200 ) ( 300 -100 300 )`. It gives me an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception: 5` at line 79. I took a look at the code but everything seens good...

Comment: Hmm weird I guess I'll see if I can find the problem.

Comment: I've got a problem I ran the code with your file and I'm not getting an error... by the way I did asume that every of those brushes is at it's own line.

Comment: The file is like: `// brush from cube <line break> ( 400 100 200 ) <line break> ( 300 -100 300 ) <line break> // brush from cube <line break> ( 400 100 200 ) ( 300 -100 300 )`

Comment: Ah that's why. My method requires // brush from cube ( 400 100 200 ) ( 300 -100 300 ) to all be on one line. By the way how do you do the gray highlighting? And I'll rewrite the method to match your needs. :)

Comment: By the way are there also carriage returns in the output?

Comment: What would be _carriage returns in the output_. Thanks, I'll test try 2.

Comment: Oh, I forgot mention that `usemtl texture <line break> ceil` is if the "someNumber" at the center after `wall` is if the number is positive and `usemtl texture <line break> floor` is negative.

Comment: I do the gray highlighting with à code à == `code` (the symbol at the top of a that I don't know the name)

Comment: Ah ok and by the way a cariage return is a line break or \n

Comment: The code probably doesn't work properly (because of your expination) but I'll (or you) make a new version :)

Comment: I'm trying here, :D but I just know how to make the cariage return. D:

Comment: \n is a cariage return just put it in a string "\n"